# Flutter Web - is it possible to listen to keystroke events?

Tags: javascript, flutter, flutter-web

I have built a multi-platform chat app - on mobile, there is a send button that the user must tap, but on Web I want the user to be able to send messages just by pressing "Enter" on their keyboard when they're focused on the text field. Is this possible?

Thank you!